# October CMS with AWS Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, octobercms, octobercms-backend, amazon-cloudfront

I have a setup where there are 3 load balanced instances with october cms in it, where the theme is being loaded from EFS.

The load balancer is put behind a CloudFront.

However, on the default linking policy of "detect", the website breaks by trying to load the assets using the load balancer URL.

Is there any way to have it be "domain agnostic" where it can also detect the URL associated with CloudFront?

Comment: Did you try forwarding the `host` header in CloudFront? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/configure-cloudfront-to-forward-headers/

Comment: Thank you. We have found a way to do that.